# Multiple endpoints in survival analysis of individual careers

Tags: r, survival, hypothesis-testing, group-differences

I analyze labour market activities. I measure `JD`: job duration (time between beginning and ending of employment) and `PD`: professional duration (the time spent in a specific vocation). My sample is episode based (not individual based), thats important for `PD`: I measure `PD` as two subsequent job episodes in the same vocation. `PD` therefore is greater than or equal to `JD` by definition. Furthermore I have more data points for `JD` (every single employment gives a data point) than for `PD` (for every employee two subsequent employments in the same vocation are merged to one data point).

I am interested in *the difference* between `JD` and `PD` and I want to compare this difference for multiple groups.

Testing `JD` and separately `PD` isn't desirable. Suppose group `A` has a short `JD` and a slightly longer `PD`. Group `B` could then have a long `JD` but a `PD` that's only slightly longer than `B`'s `JD`. What test can be performed to check for a difference of the difference between `JD` and `PD`?

Does it makes sense to test for a difference in proportions of `JD` to `PD` in groups?

Non-sequitor: what does the `rho` do in `R`'s [`survdiff`-test](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/survival/html/survdiff.html) and how should I choose `rho`?

[edit]
My approach still seems unclear. Here's what I do exactly:

I use a database storing people's id (`ID`), begin data of an occupation (`BEGIN`), end date of an occupation (`END`) and type of occupation (`TYPE`).

- To gather `JD` I take `BEGIN` and `END` and build different groups using `TYPE`.
- To receive `PD` I do the following: For every `ID` if 2 subsequent employments (`e1`, `e2`) have the same `TYPE`, I merge them to one episode (with `BEGIN(e1)` and `END(e2)`). I repeat this step until no more merges are possible (e.g. if there are 3 subsequent employments (`e1`, `e2`, `e3`) of the same `TYPE`, I end up with one episode (with `BEGIN(e1)` and `END(e3)`)

Finally, what I try to find out is, if the difference between `JD` and `PD` follows a similar pattern for different types or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you want independent time-to-event models, you could calculate a "delta" `ID = PD-JD` or an interim duration (unemployment possibly, or time in subsequent jobs of similar function). Time-to-new-vocation is a meaningful outcome on its own. In such models, you could adjust for the `JD` by having it as a covariate/stratum variable in a Cox proportional hazards model. This would allow you to compare people of different job markets with the same duration of employment. So people in the medical field with 5 years experience versus people in the architecture field with 5 years experience would be compared in their rate of re-employment.

Looking at the fraction of `JD` to `PD` is possibly a meaningful analysis, though intuitively I don't believe there's any reason to assume that the shorter the time of employment, the shorter the time until finding another capacity.

I think you should also consider the multiple endpoints of people who float around in several jobs in the same capacity, i.e. people in a desirable market with commitment issues or contractors. It doesn't seem like you've captured that information according to your problem description.

Comment: thank you for improving my question and for your answer. I think my poor wording lead to a misconception: due to the design of the data, I cannot calculate a `ID = PD - JD` (at least I cannot do that on an individual base), because my observations are "episode based" not "indivdual based". That means, apart from `Surv(PD) >= Surv(JD)` the two samples don't have much in common...

Comment: You have disparate data sources about length of time in a certain vocation or profession and about length of time in a specific position? There's no way to link them to an individual? If that's the case, then it really makes sense to analyze the data separately. Using one dataset to structurally imply things about another can introduce a lot of bias. You can posit some conclusions about their relationship, but I would need to see individual level PD and JD to be convinced.

Comment: No, it's the same data source. Let's consider an individual that's an architect for one year, then is unemployed and then is an architect again. For `JD` that's 2 episodes (each 1 year long). For `PD` that's just 1 episode (length: 3 years). So I *could* link the episodes to individuals, still I cannot perform `ID = PD - JD` as the number of episodes is different.

Comment: So you need to explain this in your question. What exactly do you measure? Have you captured the number of episodes and the duration of episodes for each individual and PD is the length from the start of the first to the end of the last?